# Call js functions inside PHP loops while passing php variable as parameter to one of the functions

Tags: javascript, php

Ok so have created two javascipt functions and i want to call them inside a php loop while passing php variable as parameter to the second function

```
addElements($filePath)
```

this filePath variable has to be the last one from the inner loop i guess written like this will not get the first variable from the first loop

Here is what I want and what have written so far:

```
                <script>                
                <?php foreach( glob( 'posts/*' ) as $filePath ){
                        //createPost(); call js function declared in header
                        foreach( glob( $filePath.'/*' ) as $filePath ){
                        //addElements($filePath) call second hs function declared in header here i pass the last $filePath from the second loop as parameter
                        }

                }?>
              </script>
```

Another try but still doesn't work

```
<script>                
                        <?php foreach( glob( 'posts/*' ) as $filePath ){
                                //createPost(); call js function declared in header
                                echo 'createPost()';
                                foreach( glob( $filePath.'/*' ) as $filePath ){
                                //addElements($filePath) call second hs function declared in header here i pass the last $filePath from the second loop as parameter
                                echo 'addElements('.$filePath.')';
                                }

                        }?>
```

Comment: not possible. php runs on the server, js runs on the client. you cannot have PHP invoke js function calls (and have them execute) at the same time the PHP is. php can output text that contains JS function calls, and they'll run when the page is received by the client, but that's about it.

Comment: but i've seen in the net a possible solutions with echo see my edit

Comment: Strange question. PHP can output pure javascript code that is executed when the page is loaded. You just use script tags and output the javascript as part of a view. You may need to rethink your code. Try reading about .ajax() (jQuery) and passing data thru JSON encoding (PHP json_encode()).

Comment: i know there is better way using ajax and json but im not that familiar with php thats why im doing this way but im sure it can be achieved my way what i do is passing the url of a file into js function

Comment: Just be sure to realise that Javascript does not run while PHP is executing its script. Only when PHP has **finished** the script will the browser have the whole page loaded, and **only then** will the Javascript be executed.

Comment: well in my try its clear that i run javascript function before the whole php script has finished so you say its not possible with my way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is executed on the server side only so you cannot have a PHP loop that is executing javascript functions (javascript = client side). However you can generate the javascript code on your server and it will be executed on the client side.

So the easy solution is to write something like that:

```
<script>                
  <?php 
  foreach( glob( 'posts/*' ) as $filePath ){
    echo 'createPost();'; // call js function declared in header
    foreach( glob( $filePath.'/*' ) as $filePath ){
      echo 'addElements("'.$filePath.'");'; // call second hs function declared in header here i pass the last $filePath from the second loop as parameter
    }
  }
  ?>
</script>
```

It will generate something like that:

```
createPost();
addElements('filepathA');
addElements('filepathB');
addElements('filepathC');
createPost();
addElements('filepathD');
addElements('filepathE');
// ...
```

As you can see there is no loop here. Another solution is to create an array of data on your server side and using `json_encode`php function to have javascript data that you can use on the client side:

```
    <?php 
$results = [];
foreach( glob( 'posts/*' ) as $filePath ){
    $subDirs = [];
    foreach( glob( $filePath.'/*' ) as $filePath ){
        $subDirs[] = $filePath; 
    }
    $results[] = [
        'dir' => $filePath,
        'subDirs' => $subDirs
    ];
}
echo 'var data = ' . json_encode($results) . ';';
?>
```

You now have a javascript array that you can use as usual :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    createPost();
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].subDirs.length; j++){
         addElements(data[i].subDirs[j]);
    }
}
```